# Extract text with regex between ","

Tags: regex, sequence

I have been struggling making a regex to extract the information in below divided in 3 part between the ",". Only the first and second sequence (Friday and the date has succeded).

Friday, 26 Apr 2013, 18:30

I hope someone has the experience.

Best regards

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, it is probably easier to just split the string on `,` and take the middle part. What language are you using to do the matching?

Comment: I have to agree that splitting on the `,` will make things easier than using a regex. If you are using just a regex for creating a non-deterministic finite automaton, this is a different case.

Answer (score 3):

Why not simply split the string and trim the excess whitespace of the individual parts? For example, verbosely written in C#:

```
string input = "Friday, 26 Apr 2013, 18:30";

string[] parts = input.Split(',');

for (int i = 0; i < parts.Length; i++)
{
    parts[i] = parts[i].Trim();
}

Console.WriteLine(parts[0]);    // "Friday"
Console.WriteLine(parts[1]);    // "26 Apr 2013"
Console.WriteLine(parts[2]);    // "18:30"
```

If you really want to use a regular expression for this, `^(.*),(.*),(.*)$` should work:

```
string input = "Friday, 26 Apr 2013, 18:30";

Regex regex = new Regex("^(.*),(.*),(.*)$", RegexOptions.Singleline);
Match match = regex.Match(input);

Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value.Trim());    // "Friday"
Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[2].Value.Trim());    // "26 Apr 2013"
Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[3].Value.Trim());    // "18:30"
```

Adding appropriate error checking is left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 1):

The following Regex expression is matching this whole part :

```
, 18:30
I hope someone has the experience.
Best regards

,+\s[0-9]+:[0-9]+ \r*.*
```

But yeah, that's kind of ultra specific to this ", Hour:Minuts [...]" format. You should do a split if you're using PHP or the equivalent in your language.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you really want is something like this:

```
from datetime import datetime
s="Friday, 26 Apr 2013, 18:30"
d=datetime.strptime(s, "%A, %d %b %Y, %H:%M")
d

Out[7]: datetime.datetime(2013, 4, 26, 18, 30)
```

See the [strptime](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) and [date format](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) docs for details :)

Edit: sorry, I was somehow assuming you were using Python. Other languages have similar idioms though, e.g. [PHP's date_parse](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-parse.php), C#'s [DateTime.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx), etc.

Comment: C# has a DateTime.ParseExact function which will parse out the correct parts given a format string and construct a valid DateTime object.

Comment: I must've been editing my post while you were writing your comment.. it's good to see we came to the same conclusion though! :)

Comment: I posted an answer with how to parse the date with localization in C#. Also, I mistakenly put DateTime.Parse when it should have been DateTime.ParseExact. DateTime.Parse expects dates to be in a specific format or it will fail to parse the date.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify a language so I'm going to answer this with a standard REGEX approach.

`(?<=(^|,\s+)).+?(?=(,|$))` Will work for you.

Let me break up what it's doing.

- `(?<=(^|,\s+)` - Look ahead for the start of a string or a comma followed by whitespace, but don't include it in the match. All matches must have this in front of them.
- `.+?` - Grab all characters, but don't be greedy.
- `(?=(,|$))`  - Look behind for the end of string or a comma. All matches must have this behind them.

When ran on your test case of `Friday, 26 Apr 2013, 18:30`, I get 3 matches:

- `Friday`
- `26 Apr 2013`
- `18:30`

Answer (score 0):

Like m01's answer, you could try this approach with C#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Globalization;

namespace TestDate
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string dateString = "Friday, 26 Apr 2013, 18:30"; // Modified from MSDN
            string format = "dddd, dd MMM yyyy, HH:mm";

            DateTime dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            Console.WriteLine(dateTime);
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

This will print out the localized date and time that is configured on the user's machine. For me it printed out 4/16/2013 6:30:00 PM.